# Count entries across a SQL table

Tags: sql, count, multiple-columns

I currently have a table which is within a system which I am unable to change. So not the ideal format, I know, but I need to count across 6 columns to show if there is something entered and then put the sum in a final column. The entries are text and so I just need to know the total across the 6 columns.

```
[data1]
[data2]
[data3]
[data4]
[data5]
[data6]
--To be created [totalcount]
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  And how do you "count" text?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
select t.*,
       ( (case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col5 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col6 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as num_notnull
from t;
```

Comment: HI - That seems to just count the columns. So I get a total of 6 . The columns are blank though on the entries I have checked.

Comment: However I have just tried >'0' instead of not null and that worked. Always a way hey. Thanks for your help Gordon

Comment: `0` is also a value and you wanted `if there is something entered` so `Gordon` has checked `NULL` only, which is correct according to you question.

Comment: @HAS . . . Your question is sort of ambiguous (I think `NULL` is a very reasonable interpretation of "blank" in a SQL context).  But the better comparison for a string is `> ''`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to consider is if an empty string (`''`) is considered empty or not. Then you can do the following for the entire table:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col1 IS NULL OR T.Col1 = '' THEN 1 END) Col1Blanks,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col2 IS NULL OR T.Col2 = '' THEN 1 END) Col2Blanks,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col3 IS NULL OR T.Col3 = '' THEN 1 END) Col3Blanks,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col4 IS NULL OR T.Col4 = '' THEN 1 END) Col4Blanks,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col5 IS NULL OR T.Col5 = '' THEN 1 END) Col5Blanks,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col6 IS NULL OR T.Col6 = '' THEN 1 END) Col6Blanks
FROM
    YourTable T
```

If you need the total of all of them (`ISNULL` is a SQL Server function, every DMBS has one equivalent):

```
SELECT
    X.Col1Blanks,
    X.Col2Blanks,
    X.Col3Blanks,
    X.Col4Blanks,
    X.Col5Blanks,
    X.Col6Blanks,
    ISNULL(X.Col1Blanks, 0) +
        ISNULL(X.Col2Blanks, 0) +
        ISNULL(X.Col3Blanks, 0) +
        ISNULL(X.Col4Blanks, 0) +
        ISNULL(X.Col5Blanks, 0) +
        ISNULL(X.Col6Blanks, 0) TotalBlanks
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col1 IS NULL OR T.Col1 = '' THEN 1 END) AS Col1Blanks,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col2 IS NULL OR T.Col2 = '' THEN 1 END) AS Col2Blanks,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col3 IS NULL OR T.Col3 = '' THEN 1 END) AS Col3Blanks,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col4 IS NULL OR T.Col4 = '' THEN 1 END) AS Col4Blanks,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col5 IS NULL OR T.Col5 = '' THEN 1 END) AS Col5Blanks,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Col6 IS NULL OR T.Col6 = '' THEN 1 END) AS Col6Blanks
    FROM
        YourTable T
    ) X
```